# React JS - cloneElement example?

Tags: reactjs

When I change the inline style of a component depending on the state, I get this error.

```
Warning: `div` was passed a style object that has previously been mutated. Mutating `style` is deprecated.
```

In my render function, I'm calling this function before the return, to check a property.

```
this._isGameOver();
```

_isGameOver:

```
_isGameOver()
{
    if (this.props.gameOver === false)
    {
        style.well.backgound = '#f5f5f5';
        style.h1.color = '#32936F';
    }
    else
    {
        style.well.background = 'red';
        style.h1.color = 'white';

    }
}
```

So where and how do I use this clone? The documentation doesn't give any solid examples.

Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `cloneElement` in your example, simply return a new style object instead of mutating the existing one.

```
_isGameOver() {
    if (this.props.gameOver === false) {
      return {
        well: { background: '#f5f5f5' },
        h1: { color: '#32936F' }
      }
    }
    else return {
      well: { background: 'red' },
      h1: { color: 'white' }
    }
}
```

Then you can merge the new styles with the old styles wherever you need using something like `Object.assign`

```
var newStyle = this._isGameOver()

return <h1 style={Object.assign({}, style.h1, newStyle.h1)} />
```

Comment: You know, this is exactly how I was doing it before but I figured it was bad practice... Why, I don't know, but it did solve the problem. I just read on the React website about cloning and figured that should be the better way to do it.

Comment: Treating data as immutable, especially nowadays, is considered best practice. Things are much more predictable that way and the cost of immutability on performance is low, and even lower with things like Immutable.js

Comment: I'll stick to that method so, as it is very easy ans straight forward to work with. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're defining that `style` object outside of your component (perhaps importing it?). So wherever you're going to modify that style you need to make a clone of it.

I always import as `baseStyles` (to indicate it shouldn't be mutated) and use `lodash.cloneDeep()` (because cloning deep objects is fiddly to do yourself).

So your function becomes

```
import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';
import baseStyle from '../blah/yourStyle.js';

_isGameOver()
{
    const style = cloneDeep(baseStyle);
    if (this.props.gameOver === false)
    {
        style.well.backgound = '#f5f5f5';
        style.h1.color = '#32936F';
    }
    else
    {
        style.well.background = 'red';
        style.h1.color = 'white';

    }
}
```

You could also do something like:

```
const wellStyle = {
    ...style.well,
    background: '$f5f5f5',
}
```

and then pass `wellStyle` to your component rather than `style.well`.

It might not suit your situation, but I only change styles inside the actual render method. It keeps everything in the one place (cloning your import in more than one place won't work).

Comment: I'm not even importing my styles, I just keep them below the class in an object and call them when necessary. I've tried putting them in a separate file, but I can't get it to work. Would you have any examples of how the js file of styles should look? I find it hard to see examples anywhere.